# Change value of a dataframe column based on the column names present in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df2` which has data like below

```
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                'NAME': ['JOHN', 'MARY', 'MATT', 'TIM'],
                'EFF_D': ['11-22-2001', '12-19-2002', '04-11-2002', '04-11-2002'],
                'EFF_D_NI': ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y'],
                'END_D': ['11-22-2001', '12-19-2002', '04-11-2002', '04-11-2002'],
                'END_D_NI': ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
                'OPEN_D': ['11-22-2001', '12-19-2002', '04-11-2002', 'None'],
                'OPEN_D_NI': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'Y'],
                'AMT': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
                'AMT_NI': ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N'],
                'STATUS': ['A', 'X', 'Z', 'A']})
```

I need to change the value of the columns `EFF_D` to NULL when `EFF_D_NI =='Y'`. I need to do it for a set columns which are present in another dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column': ['EFF_D', 'END_D', 'OPEN_D', 'AMT'],
                'Null_IND_COLUMN'': ['EFF_D_NI', 'END_D_NI', 'OPEN_D_NI', 'AMT_NI']})
```

How can I do it dynamically?

Expected o/p

```
O/P                                     
ID  NAME    EFF_D   EFF_D_NI    END_D   END_D_NI    OPEN_D  OPEN_D_NI   AMT AMT_NI  STATUS
1   JOHN    NULL    Y   NULL    Y   11-22-2001  N   1000    Y   A
2   MARY    12-19-2002  N   NULL    Y   12-19-2002  N   2000    N   X
3   MATT    NULL    Y   NULL    Y   04-11-2002  N   NULL    Y   Z
4   TIM NULL    Y   NULL    Y   NULL    Y   4000    N   A
```

I am new to Python and would like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dictionary first with `Column` as key and `Null_IND_COLUMN` as value from `df1`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column': ['EFF_D', 'END_D', 'OPEN_D', 'AMT'],
                'Null_IND_COLUMN': ['EFF_D_NI', 'END_D_NI', 'OPEN_D_NI', 'AMT_NI']})
dic = pd.Series(df1.Null_IND_COLUMN.values, index=df1.Column).to_dict()
dic
```

```
{'EFF_D': 'EFF_D_NI',
 'END_D': 'END_D_NI',
 'OPEN_D': 'OPEN_D_NI',
 'AMT': 'AMT_NI'}
```

Now use this dictionary to update the column values using `apply`. Here I have put `np.nan` instead of NULL.

```
for k, v in dic.items():
    df2[k] = df2.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x[v] == 'Y' else x[k], axis=1)
```

Output
[image]